# What is the Magento 1.7 REST API url?

Tags: api, magento, rest, magento-1.7

What is the URL to make REST requests on magento?

My Magento install is running at server root on `http://myserver.com/`, without a magento directory.

How do I know the URL?

Answer (score 3):

All URLs in REST API have the following base URL.

```
  http://myserver.com/api/rest/
```

For example if you want the list of customers in Magento, using a GET HTTP method:

```
  http://myserver.com/api/rest/customers
```

where

```
http://myserver.com/api/rest/ - endpoint
/customers - action URL
```

Answer (score 2):

The REST [wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction_to_rest_api) has the information you need.

```
https://magentohost.example.com/api/rest/
```

Answer (score 2):

http://myserver.com/index.php/api for Soap
http://myserver.com/index.php/api/rest for REST